How to populate data in one column based on substring of another column when dealing with a large number of conditions
I want to populate the data in an empty column based on the substring search match of another column.
I have managed to achieve this based on the answer provided here: How do I create a new column where the values are selected based on existing columns?
Specifically, this answer.
However, my issue/question is I'm working with 80+ conditions so making changes to each line under:
conditions = [
    (df['Set'] == 'Z') & (df['Type'] == 'A'),
    ...80 lines of code
    (df['Type'] == 'B')]

and tracking the correct location for the parameter value within the choices has become cumbersome:
choices = ['yellow', 'blue', 'purple' ...80 values ]

Is there a better way to manage these 2 lists via maybe a config file?
Which is essentially the output of the dataframe i.e.
Z  &        A  yellow
Z  &        B    blue
X  ==       B  purple
Y  default  C   black

Currently I'm using a solution which creates a new line for every additional condition I need to cater for.

Since the conditions are essentially equalities, and assuming always the same set of columns, you could use a merge and fillna:
#              Set  Type  color
conditions = [('Z', 'A', 'yellow'),
              ('Z', 'B', 'blue'),
              ('X', 'B', 'purple'),
             ]

out = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(conditions, columns=['Set', 'Type', 'color']),
               how='left').fillna({'color': 'black'})

An alternative if you want to be able to assign to the original dataframe:
df['color'] = (df
               .reset_index()
               .merge(pd.DataFrame(conditions, columns=['Set', 'Type', 'color']))
               .set_index('index')['color']
               .reindex(df.index, fill_value='black')
               )

Output:
  Type Set   color
0    A   Z  yellow
1    B   Z    blue
2    B   X  purple
3    C   Y   black

